# Check if File Exists Informatica Workflow

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to figure out a way to check if the file exists before running a session.

I currently have a command line task before a sessions that does the following:

IF EXIST TEST*.TXT 
EXIT 0
ELSE 
EXIT 1

I want to use the ErrorCode value on the link task, but I have no luck getting it to work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **Command** task with this command:

**test -f $PMTargetFileDir/fdata.txt; echo $((1/$?))**

Comment: Giving this a try

Comment: I pasted it into a command task, what output should I be expecting? I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

1) If the file exists **$?** equals to 0.

2) If the file does not exist **$?** equals to 1.

So, in 1) $((1/$?)) will cause th error (division by zero). After the **Command** task you can add two or one of these links: first with the condition **$TaskName.PrevTaskStatus=SUCCEEDED**, and second with **$TaskName.PrevTaskStatus=FAILED**.

Answer (score 0):

Create a command task just before your main session

Link this command task to main session and put link condition as $prevtaskstatus=succeeded

and write below code in Command task

head -2 /testfiledir/test.txt

Command task will fail if file does not exist and succeeds if file exist.